# Wordpress: How to Remove this from my Blog?

Tags: wordpress

At my blog -> http://studiodeideias.blog.br/

There is a "image caption" that I want to remove. Every time you pass the mouse on it, it gets darker (hoover effect).

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to get rid of it? What results did you get when making those attempts? Have you narrowed down the problem to any particular set of files? Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself and show what you tried or at least narrow down the source of the problem in your question.

Comment: I used the Chrome Inspect Elemet function to find the div, when I found I removed and notice that it worked, but only for 1 image on the slider.

Comment: Then I triend to remove in the header.php file, and my theme broked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want to remove is the hover effect, you should remove this lines of code from your style.css file

```
#feature-slider .entry-container:hover {
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-border-radius:     4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  4px;
    border-radius:          4px; 
    -moz-transition:    all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
    transition:         all 0.2s ease-in-out;      
}
```

Once you do that, you're golden.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to delete the whole thing, hoover effect, text. The entire div.

Comment: Well, there you have it. Delete the whole thing. Find out which file it is coming from in your wordpress theme and delete the mark-up related to it. As of now, your website is down, so there's nothing we can do to help